# What the best solution to receive a lot of data in an Android application

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app (API 8) that need to receive a lot of data when the user connect for the first time.
The App is an Catalog/Items based app where the Items contains huge text.
In the Web Database I have more than 1000 records and about 8MB of data to transfer.

What the best solution for that ?

I tried XML file but the device sometimes freeze try to parse these data and I lost the connection.

Regards,

RG

Comment: Have you tried creating an xml file for each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a large amount to transfer via XML.

What if you requested it, say, 10 records at a time and stop when no more results are returned?

Also -- make sure you're doing it on a background thread (AsyncTask)!!

Answer (score 0):

As elijah says, use an `AsyncTask` or some other background process.

Also - is that 8MB of uncompressed XML data? If so then ZIP it - it will compress a great deal. If the 8MB is already compressed then try minifying the XML see [Minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). Basically removing unnecessary whitespace.

This...

```
<elements>
    <element>
        ...
    </element>
    <element>
        ...
    </element>
</elements>
```

...is as good as the following when it comes to XML...

```
<elements><element>...</element><element>...</element></elements>
```